# Tensorflow Error: "Label IDs must < n_classes", but my Label IDs appear to meet this requirement already

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to create a Python 3 program to classify sentences into categories using Tensorflow. However, I'm getting a very lengthy series of errors when I try to run my code. The following error appears to be the foundation of my issue:

> **InvalidArgumentError:** assertion failed: [Label IDs must < n_classes] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:x (linear/head/ToFloat:0) = ] [[4][4][1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)...] [y (linear/head/assert_range/Const:0) = ] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzoEG.png)

I am using Scikit-Learn's `LabelEncoder()` method to create label IDs, which should meet this requirement; their [documentation page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) says, "*Encode labels with value between `0` and `n_classes-1`.*"

The code I am trying to run is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


data_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') #data.csv has 2 columns: "Category", and "Description"

features = data_df.drop('Category', axis=1) #drop Category column
lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
labels = lab_enc.fit_transform(data_df['Category']) #Encode labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1
labels = pd.Series(labels) #pandas_input_func needs the labels in Series format    

features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)


description = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket('Description', hash_bucket_size=1000)
feat_cols = [description]

input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=features_train, y=labels_train, batch_size=100, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)

model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feat_cols)
model.train(input_fn=input_func, steps=1000)
```

The data.csv file I'm using is a small set of gibberish test data:
[image: Testing data]

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed. I've only found one post referencing a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813746/tensorflow-invalid-argument-assertation-failed-label-ids-must-n-classes), but that user's issue appeared to be of a different nature to mine, if I'm understanding correctly.

Any insights are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need the same number of labels as you have categories.  Not sure how to set that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```py
# Explicitly specify the number of classes, e.g. 10
model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feat_cols, n_classes=10)
```

The default value `n_classes=2`, which internally means that tensorflow uses sigmoid cross entropy loss. Setting the number of classes will make it a softmax cross entropy.

Comment: Thanks so much! That turned out to be it. I guess I didn't expect the classifier to need a number of classes to be explicitly defined that way. Can you tell me if there is any benefit to making n_classes more than n_classes actually is? I made n_classes=len(lab_enc.classes_) since that will give me the exact number of unique labels.

Comment: This is because tensorflow is building a graph before it reads the data. And the first thing it does is selects the classifier - binary or multi-class. I think the real problem here is the error message which is confusing.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. I'd forgotten that tensorflow operates with placeholders and such when building the computational graph. Thanks a bunch for the help!